# 'memory not mapped' Error in R on Solaris 10

Tags: r, rcpp, solaris-10

I am writing an R package for CRAN and get an error message on Solaris 10.

```
library(BET)
X1 <- rnorm(128)
X2 <- rnorm(128)
Y <- 0.2 * (X1 + X2) + sqrt(0.92) * rnorm(128)
BEAST(cbind(X1, X2, Y), 3, test.independence = TRUE,
    index = list(c(1,2), c(3)), test.uniformity = FALSE, p.value.method = NA)
```

Version: 0.3.4

Check: examples

Result: ERROR

```
Running examples in ‘BET-Ex.R’ failed
The error most likely occurred in:


> ### Name: BEAST
> ### Title: Binary Expansion Approximate Symmetry Test
> ### Aliases: BEAST
>
> ### ** Examples
>
> X1 <- rnorm(128)
> X2 <- rnorm(128)
> Y <- 0.2 * (X1 + X2) + sqrt(0.92) * rnorm(128)
> BEAST(cbind(X1, X2, Y), 3, test.independence = TRUE,
+ index = list(c(1,2), c(3)), test.uniformity = FALSE, p.value.method = NA)

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: BeastCpp(X, d, m, B, unif.margin, lambda, test.uniformity, test.independence, index, null.simu, p.value.method, num.permutations)
 2: BEAST(cbind(X1, X2, Y), 3, test.independence = TRUE, index = list(c(1, 2), c(3)), test.uniformity = FALSE, p.value.method = NA)
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
```

Flavor: r-patched-solaris-x86

I tried to replicate this error with R-hub but it works well.

Comment: can we see `BeastCpp` code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is the first time I ask a question on stackoverflow. `BeastCpp` includes hundreds of line that I have no idea whether and how I can share it with you.

Comment: That may make it hard to help you.  While _some things_ are different on the Solaris box, the above may suggest a general error.  Of course, it could just be in the interface to BEAST, or in BEAST itself.  The Solaris has different 'endianness' from the x86_64 processors so if some fancy bitmapping occurs it could be a legitimate bug.  But again: impossible for us to tell.  You need a _minimally reproducible complete example_.  This isn't one, sorry!

Comment: I see you have a new version 0.3.5 on CRAN with [this changeset](https://github.com/cran/BET/commit/27a0d57ea3938b7f69d9933aaf97be9d681f7070).  I guess it would be nice if you could report back here, or on the r-package-devel list where you crossposted, what the issue was, and how you fixed it.

Comment: I failed to fix the problem in 0.3.5. I just wanted to go back to the previous version since I've never meet this error before. I will keep checking it on Solaris 10.

Comment: @Wan It would be great to know what you did as a workaround.

Comment: @F. Privé Have to temporarily make it \dontrun, still haven't figure that out.